# Python: saving in file big entries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to save in a file (don't mind the type) some string informations about entries and objects. I can generate the string from my data and I know how to save a string in a .txt file. However, when I'm reading from the file, I'm reading "lines", so I'm assuming it reads a line till the first new line symbol. However, some of my strings are longer than a document line and when I want to read it, I get errors. How I can save a long string in a file to not loose any data?

It is, how I'm saving in the file:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'a', "utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data_string + '\n')
```

and how I read the data from the file:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r',"utf-8") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
```

Comment: You aren't losing data with the code you've shown.  It's not clear what's wrong without some example data perhaps and a reproducible complete program.

Comment: It will be interesting if you mention the length of one string you can not save so that I can test.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

## dump/load as JSON

```
import tempfile
import json

text = 'this is my string with a \nnewline in it'

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps([text]))
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    lines = json.load(f)
    print(lines)
```

Downsides: JSON may be fairly human readable, but a little error in your file will bork everything up. Not nearly as legible as plain ol' text.

## pickle

```
import tempfile
import pickle

text = 'this is my string with a \nnewline in it'

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+') as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps([text]))
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    lines = pickle.load(f)
    print(lines)
```

Downsides: pickle is [terribly insecure](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/playing-pickle-security/) and you should pretty much treat it as you would `eval`. If you wouldn't feel comfortable using `eval` in that situation, then you shouldn't use pickle.

## Your own [sentinel](https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/)

```
import tempfile

text = 'this is my string with a \nnewline in it'
other_text = 'this line has no newline in it'

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+') as f:
    f.write(text)
    f.write(chr(30))
    f.write(other_text)
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    lines = f.read().split(chr(30))
    print(lines)
```

Downsides: Could be a little trickier. You have to make sure that your sentinel isn't found in the text itself. Also you can't use `readlines`, and iterating line by line is made a bit more awkward.